# Why does interface extends Record<string, ...> allow numeric keys?

Tags: typescript, generics

I am trying to find a relatively generic way to type POST bodies and the responses I get back in conjunction with their API routes (in a nextjs app).

For this I want the compiler to force me to add a `body` type and a `return` type to all the API routes, which I achieved with the following interface:

```
export interface PostTypeMapping extends Record<string, {body: unknown, return: unknown}> {
  "/api/taskCompletions": {body: PostCompletionBody, return: void},
  "/api/task": {body: PostTaskBody, return: void},
}
```

So far so good. I can use this type in my API route like so:

```
 async (req, res: NextApiResponse<PostTypeMapping["api/task"]["return"]>) => {
  //...
}
```

But when I try to write a wrapper that automatically infers the POST body and the return type from the URL, I get an error in the line with `await fetch(url,`:

> Argument of type 'keyof PostTypeMapping' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestInfo'.
> Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'RequestInfo'

```
export async function fetchPost<T extends keyof PostTypeMapping>(url: T, body: PostTypeMapping[T]["body"]): Promise<PostTypeMapping[T]["return"]> {
  try {
    const res = await fetch(url, { // <- The error above occurs here
      method: "POST",
      body: JSON.stringify(body),
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    });
    if(res.status === 201 || res.status === 204){
      return;
    }
    return res.json();
  } catch (err: any){
    return {message: "Fehler: " + err.message};
  }
}
```

### Why can `url`, which is typed as `keyof PostTypeMapping`, be a number?

I investigated further and for the most part, the `extends Record<string, {body: unknown, return: unknown}>` does seem to do what I want (force me to add a body and return type to all the entries of the interface), but allows numeric keys as well as strings. Why? Both cases that are not allowed are good.

```
export interface PostTypeMapping extends Record<string, {body: unknown, return: unknown}> {
  "/api/taskCompletions": {body: PostCompletionBody, return: void},
  "/api/task": {body: PostTaskBody, return: void},
  1: {body: void, return: void}, // why is this legal? 1 is not a string
  2: "asd" // not allowed -> Property '2' of type '"asd"' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ body: unknown; return: unknown; }'
  "asd": "asd" // not allowed -> Property '"asd"' of type '"asd"' is not assignable to 'string' index type '{ body: unknown; return: unknown; }
}
```

[typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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-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)

*EDIT*:

A simplified reproduction of the problem can be found at https://tsplay.dev/Nr5X2w thanks to T.J. Crowder

Comment: Keys of objects can only be strings or symbols. Anything else is converted to a string. If you do `myObj[1] = "hello"`  or `{1: "hello" }`  that adds a string key `"1"`. Same way how if you do `{ foo: "world" }` you get the string `"foo"` as key.

Comment: Then why do I get the error in my Post wrapper `Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'RequestInfo'`?

Comment: @Taxel - What is the definition of `RequestInfo`? I don't see that anywhere in your question other than the text. But it sounds like you're trying to assign a number to a variable/property/parameter that is defined as an object type.

Comment: `RequestInfo` is the definition of the first argument for `fetch`: `function fetch(input: RequestInfo, init?: RequestInit | undefined): Promise<Response>`.
From `lib.dom.d.ts`: `type RequestInfo = Request | string;`

Comment: @Taxel - That `RequestInfo` is `type RequestInfo = Request | string;`, where `Request` is an object type. Numbers are neither strings nor objects, so you can't assign a number to it. But I guess TypeScript treats object property names specially, since as you say, you can use `1` (which is converted to `"1"`) in an object literal assigned to `Record<string, any>`, even though you can't use a `number` where a string parameter is expected: https://tsplay.dev/N7OoBN Just another of TypeScript's pragmatic choices I suspect.

Comment: But that doesn't really explain it, and I have to say I really don't get it. The key type of `Record<string, any>` is `string`. So far so good. The key type of an interface extending `Record<string, any>`, though, isn't just `string` (which is fair enough) but also includes `number` (which seems odd). Here's a simpler repro: https://tsplay.dev/Nr5X2w

Comment: The question here is really "why does `Record<string, XXX>` *prohibit* `number` keys when other types with string index signatures *allow* them?".  And it looks like it might fall out of [the support for numeric/symbol keys added in TS2.9](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types); somehow `Record<string, XXX>` is left as a mapped type and does not explicitly become a string index signature until you start doing other stuff to it.  Seems weird though.

Comment: Okay, the answer is at https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48269.  Numeric keys are allowed for string index signatures and always have been, but `keyof {[k: string]: any}` being `string | number` was introduced in TS2.9.  `Record<string, any>` should be equivalent to `{[k: string]: any}` conceptually but is implemented as a mapped type and this is not augmented, in order for mapped types to have proper variance (e.g., `Record<K, X>` is assignable to `Record<P, X>` iff `P` is assignable to `K`), and the inconsistency cannot be eliminated.

Comment: @Taxel would you like me to write up an answer with this information?  Or am I missing something about the question?

Comment: @jcalz it would be great if you could write the answer with that.

Comment: Okay I'll do it when I get a chance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See [microsoft/TypeScript#48269](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48269) for an authoritative answer to this question.

Numeric keys have always been allowed for string [index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), because non-`symbol` keys in JavaScript are always coerced to strings first. So the  "`number`" keys should really be more like "numeric strings", but TypeScript allows you to think of them as numbers to support indexing into arrays with numbers.

Prior to TypeScript 2.9, `keyof {[k: string]: any}` would have just been `string`.  But TypeScript 2.9 introduced [support for `number` and `symbol` properties with `keyof`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-9.html#support-number-and-symbol-named-properties-with-keyof-and-mapped-types).  Part of this change is that `keyof X` where `X` has a string index signature now includes `number`.  So `keyof {[k: string]: any}` is `string | number`.  This is working as intended.

But for [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) like `Record`, the compiler does not immediately augment the keys this way.  Apparently it is important that `Record<K, V>` be properly [contravariant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) in `K` (according to the [comment in ms/TS#48269](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48269#issuecomment-1068278045) anyway).

But `Record<string, any>` is, after all, *equivalent* to `{[k: string]: any}`, and therefore we have an inconsistency.  TypeScript doesn't take consistency as its most important design goal; indeed, it is a [non-goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) of TypeScript to have a provably correct type system.  Productivity is, in some sense, more important than correctness.  If fixing an inconsistency would make TypeScript very annoying to use for a lot of people, then it's better to leave the inconsistency.  And this is apparently one of those situations; according to the [same comment](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48269#issuecomment-1068278045), the inconsistency here can't be eliminated (presumably without destroying some oft-used part of the language, such as numeric keys for arrays), so it stays.

Oh well!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. If someone is interested in the very simple fix I added to make my code work: `await fetch(url.toString(), //...` did the trick.