# Typescript how to return key type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I can’t find information on how to correctly return exactly the type of a certain property of the type, passing the key in another field.

Can someone tell me or point out what I'm doing wrong? :(

```typescript
type TUser = {
    age: number,
    initials: {
        name: string
    }
}

type TRendererFunctionArgs<TValues> = {
    value: TValues[keyof TValues],
}

type TRenderer<TValues> = {
    name: keyof TValues,
    renderer: ({ value }: TRendererFunctionArgs<TValues>) => string,
}

const renderer : TRenderer<TUser> = {
    name: 'initials',
    renderer: ({ value }) => value.name, // <--- There is problem because. value : value: number | {name: string}
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKgqgZwgJygXigbwLACgoFQCGA5hAFxQB2ArgLYBGKANHoVAJZUfAdEA2CSjnztCVInQpQEwZFxJtCAXzyrceUJFgAlCFQAmKFADEaVAMa8A9lQCCyEggA8MAGoCaEBAD50WJQIAN09pd1CEAG0AawgQawAzWA9+LwQAXVZcdU1waBg9Q2NkVxS0vwwRdgkpSlj4pPDU7yz2ZH0jduRKAApMKBDmqGVKAo7is0sbe0cXJvKASnQ-WXkqEiyc3AtbWSh2oq6oUcLOlFdEFAqA0QIa6QByLh4+QQfWwgOz7qg+gdDhks0H5Bl4AHT3ZhQAD00KgzgAtEjYAALYycBBQMDIawMfgQOhQJgWIg0JBg-5DSig6S0RgoKAAHyw90oqwU6nUQA)

Comment: This is probably closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71825106/why-does-interface-extends-recordstring-allow-numeric-keys

Comment: In complete code renderer has several params in func args. This is sample.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an approach that uses a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) as an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
type TUser = {
    age: number,
    initials: {
        name: string
    }
}

type TRenderer<TValues> = { [K in keyof TValues]-?: {
    name: K;
    renderer: ({ value }: { value: TValues[K] }) => string;
} }[keyof TValues];

const renderer : TRenderer<TUser> = {
    name: 'initials',
    renderer: ({ value }) => value.name
}
```

Comment: I have linked to the docs in my answer. The `-?` just removes a potential "optional" modifier from the properties. None exist in your specific `TUser` example, so you could remove it.